# Adding new row to a table on button click in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and needed some help on how to add a new row to a  on button click.

I have written a code which has a table with 8 rows each with a text box. Performing some operations in the code behind file and if the criteria is not met, trying to display an error message. But the message is not getting displayed when I run the code.

Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong? Giving below the code snippet that I created.

// Code to create table

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="ImprStTable" width="60%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center">Mention Below The Text</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ImprSt8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

// Code behind snippet to show error msg

```
Protected Sub final_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles final.Click
    Dim iImprStCount As Integer
    Dim Row As TableRow
    Dim errCell As TableCell

    For i = 1 To 8
        If (ImprStTable.Rows.Item(i).ToString <> "") Then
            iImprStCount = iImprStCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    If (iImprStCount < 6) Then
        Row = New TableRow()
        errCell = New TableCell()
        errCell.Text = "* Minimum 6 Impression Statements is required"  '---- Error Msg
        Row.Cells.Add(errCell)

        ImprStTable.Rows.AddAt(1, Row)
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, how can I specify a font size and color for the error msg?

Thanks in advance for your help.